# Jquery if checkbox is checked add a class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a class when a checkbox is checked.

My jquery:

```
$('input').attr("checked").change(function(){
$('div.menuitem').addClass("menuitemshow");
})
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should not use `$("input")` to select a `checkbox`, input will select all inputs. Instead you can use `input:checkbox`:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('div.menuitem').addClass("menuitemshow");
    } else {
        $('div.menuitem').removeClass("menuitemshow");
    }
});
```

Basically what this does is execute whatever is inside the `function(){}` when the checkbox is changed. Then you can just use jQuery `is` to check if the checkbox is checked or not..

Comment: Ok, can you post the HTML you are using? It's hard to try and diagnose the problem without seeing that too.

Comment: If the accepted answer doesn't work for you, give the solution provided by Dinesh Gunarathne a try.

Answer (score 7):

```
// if checkbox checked then backgorund color will be gray
// there should be a input type check box with a parent class label.

 $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')) 
       $(this).parent().addClass('selected'); 
  else 
      $(this).parent().removeClass('selected')
 });

// input check box should be like this
<label class="" ><input type="checkbox" name="blabla" /></label>
```

this will add the "selected" class into the label tag()

```
//css
.selected {
background:gray
}
```

Comment: This should be marked the correct answer. The accepted answer adds the class to every div.menuitem whereas this one only adds the class to the parent of the item clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('input').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('div.menuitem').addClass("menuitemshow");
    }
});
```

You cannot have a change event on an attribute, instead check the change event of the checkbox itself and run a condition to see if it's been checked.

Comment: i'd add else block with removeClass

Comment: The OP never specified that in the question, so it's best to just fix the problem they're having, they can modify it when they're ready.

Comment: I did $('div.menuitem').removeClass("menuitem")addClass("menuitemshow"); and the class is removed, but on browser refresh the class menuitem is added again although the checkbox is still checked

Comment: Yes? The changed event fires when you change it, not on load... you could use `.trigger()` to force the change or handle it correctly server side.

Answer (score 2):

I'm making the assumption you'll want to toggle the class with the checkbox.

```
$('input').change(function(){
  var $this = $(this), $div = $('div.menuitem');
  if( $this.is(':checked') )
  {
    $div.addClass('show');
  }
  else
  {
    $div.removeClass('show');
  }
}).change();
```

I've updated this to be a *suggested* solution @Rails beginner's issue given the comments I've read so far.

Note the addition of `change()` on the last line. This is to force `change` to execute immediately on page load (I'm assuming `$('input')` waits for `document.ready` or is *after* the `input:checkbox` is created).

Comment: This isn't right, he doesn't want to add the class to the checkbox, instead to the `div.menuitem`

Comment: I want to change the class on the div when the checkbox is checked

Comment: @Rails beginner, you want to turn `div.menuitem` into `div.menuitemshow` rather than `div.menuitem.menuitemshow`? I would suggest toggling the class `show` so that `div.menuitem` turns into `div.menuitem.show` it's much more modular that way.

Comment: Yes what about when browser refresh would a checked checkbox still have the class div.menuitem.show ?

Comment: @Rails beginner, every time a browser is refreshed it essentially "forgets" the state of the webpage. There are a few ways of storing persistent client-side data across web requests, but in this case, it's simply a manner of checking the state of the checkbox when the page first loads, which is exactly what the call to `change()` does.

Comment: When the checkbox is changed the page reloads

Comment: @Rails beginner, *wait what?* You should add that to your question as it's an important piece of information. Is there a *reason* that the page reloads? I assume you're running some other script. If there's a server side language involved, then you ought to be setting the checkbox's state on the server.

Comment: Yes there is a script that submits the form when checkbox is changed, therefor there is a page refresh.

Comment: Is it not possiable to make an ajax request when the form is submitted and the content the only content that is refreshed is the content in the div with the id of rightcontent?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
         $('div.menuitem').addClass("menuitemshow");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.vfb-checkbox input:checkbox').change(function(){
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('.vfb-checkbox label').addClass("checked");
    } else {
        $('.vfb-checkbox label').removeClass("checked");
    }
});
```

```css
.vfb-checkbox{
  width:180px;
  height:130px;
 background:url('http://i304.photobucket.com/albums/nn181/Amam_Dewan/2932337756_1845773ed4_q_d_zpsea5idhnt.jpg');
}
/* checkboxes */

.vfb-checkbox label {
    cursor: pointer;
     display: block;
     position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;

 }

.vfb-checkbox label:hover{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.7) url(http://i304.photobucket.com/albums/nn181/Amam_Dewan/selected_zpsvfoaira0.png)center center no-repeat;
}

 
.vfb-checkbox input[type=checkbox] {  
     display: none;
 }
 
.checked{
       background: rgba(0,0,0,.4) url('http://i304.photobucket.com/albums/nn181/Amam_Dewan/selected_zpsvfoaira0.png') center center no-repeat;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vfb-checkbox">
  <label id="checkbox" for="check1">
    <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="vfb-checkbox">
  <label id="checkbox" for="check1">
    <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1">
  </label>
</div>
```

I used jquery in checkbox. When I clicked on one element the other elements are effected. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    $('div.menuitem').toggleClass('menuitemshow', this.checked);
})
```