# Nested relative selectors in :has()?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Say I have

```
<div id="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-div"></div>
  <div class="inner-div"></div>
</div>
```

I want to select `outer-div`

```
.outer-div:has(> .inner-div:has(+ inner-div)) {...}
```

does not work.

1. can I nest relative selectors like this anyway?
2. how best to select a parent with 2 specific children in it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to select an outer div that has exactly two inner divs which have class inner div, or that has two or more such inner divs?

Comment: 2 or more should be fine for my purposes

Answer (score 4):

Oh - nesting cannot be done

> The :has() pseudo-class cannot be nested within another :has().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

---

`#outer-div:has(> .inner-div + .inner-div)` works to select "a parent with a child who is a sibling" which is sufficient

Comment: Thanks for adding this reply. It's the first Google result for `css nested has` and so saved me time parsing through documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> how best to select a parent with 2 specific children in it?

Here is a solution which can realize the effect but does not need nested relative selectors:

```css
.outer-div{
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}

.outer-div:has(.inner-div+.inner-div){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-div">1</div>
  <div class="inner-div">1</div>
</div>

<div class="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-div">2</div>
  <div class="inner-div1">2</div>
</div>

<div class="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-div">3</div>
</div>
```

And here is the pen: https://codepen.io/lerner-zhang/pen/OJdzyPp

And hopefully this answer would be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77499244/3552975